# show one paragraph at a time and hide others - news ticker

Tags: jquery, html, css

This ticker is working right but has one problem that is, i want to show a current active paragraph and want to hide the other paragraphs at that time, so that, only current para will show at a time. I don't want to use CSS to set a particular height so it can hide the below para's. I want to do it from Jquery so that even if there is a long text, i can display it fully on the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvy41mju/).

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div class="ticker">
    <div class="ticker-inner">
        <p class="active">A brand new game designed by <strong>Me</strong>.</p>
        <p>It’s fully free.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
   div.ticker p
   {
        color: black;
        font: 1em/3em Georgia,sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
   }
</style>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
var ticker = $('.ticker'),
    tickerInner = ticker.find('.ticker-inner'),
    tickerHeight = ticker.height(),
    tickerDelay = 3000,
    tickerSpeed = 3000;

setInterval(function()
{
    // Animate top -= the height of the ticker.
    tickerInner.animate({'top' : '-='+tickerHeight}, tickerSpeed, function()
    { 
        // Move the top, hidden p to the bottom.
        $(this).find('p').first().appendTo(tickerInner);
        // This isn't totally necessary, I just like to keep my animation numbers low.
        tickerInner.css('top', 0);
    });
}, tickerDelay); // Call this every 3000ms
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `display: none` on inactive paragraphs?

Comment: its hiding even the current paragraph too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by giving `.thicker` a height, and hide the overflow:

```
div.ticker
{
    height: 3em;
    color: black;
    font: 1em/3em Georgia,sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red; /* only added so you can see it's size */
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bvy41mju/1/)

## UPDATE

Based on your comment, that the parent can't have a fixed height.

You can make that happen by first hide all the paragraphs and only show the first. Then in the interval you hide the div when you put it to the back and show the (new) first paragraph inside the inner ticker.

```
$('.ticker-inner p').hide(); /* hide all the paragraphs */
$('.ticker-inner p:first-child').show() /* show the first paragraph */

    var ticker = $('.ticker'),
     tickerInner = ticker.find('.ticker-inner'),
     tickerHeight = ticker.height(),
     tickerDelay = 3000,
     tickerSpeed = 3000;
    
    setInterval(function()
    {
        // Animate top -= the height of the ticker.
        tickerInner.animate({'top' : '-='+tickerHeight}, tickerSpeed, function()
        { 
            // Move the top, hidden p to the bottom.
            
            $(this).find('p').first().appendTo(tickerInner).hide(); /* put it to the back and hide it */
            $(this).find('p').first().show(); /* show the NEW first paragraph */
            // This isn't totally necessary, I just like to keep my animation numbers low.
            tickerInner.css('top', 0);
        });
    }, tickerDelay); // Call this every 3000ms
```

[**Updated Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/bvy41mju/7/)

Comment: i want to use this also in mobile. if i decrease the width the text also shows less. is there is a way to put the text on the new line if the text is long?

Comment: @Yatin Mistry text not coming on the next line. didn't work by adding width: 100%;

Comment: @user3400389, you are right, I added an alternative, see the update.

Comment: @LinkinTED nice one (y)

Answer (score 1):

I used `display: none` on inactive elements. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvy41mju/6/)

Basic idea is to remove the active class from all inactive elements and add active to display active elements. You'll have to adjust it a bit if you want to have more elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this fiddle : 

http://jsfiddle.net/2bayqtqf/

This is in unorder list.
```

Your Css

```
    #ticker {
            height: 67px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #ticker li {
            height: 67px;

        }
```

Your Jquery

```
    function tick()
    {   
            $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(function() {                                    $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown();    });
    }
        setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 1500);
```

Html

```
<div class="birthday">
    <ul id="ticker">
        <li>A brand new game designed by <strong>Me</strong>.</li>
        <li><p>It’s fully free.</p></li>

    </ul>   
</div>
```